# GORM in goroutines freezes if large query limit

Tags: go, go-gorm

I've decided to build service what creates CSV report.

In use: Go 1.12, GORM (as PostgreSQL ORM)

```
func main() {
  ... // init DB connection etc
  defer db.Close()
  go fetch(db)
  for {} // keeps open process
}

func fetch(db *gotm.DB) {
  .... // some code counts pages, creates file etc
  sqlLimit := 20000 // set limit
  for i := 0; i < pages; i++ {
    db.Table("reports_bookings"),Debug().Where(sql).Offset(i * sqlLimit).Limit(sqlLimit).Find(&myModels)
    .... // code: push it to file
  }
}
```

So when code tries to fetch data it just freezes. If decrease limit and set 100 for example, it runs SQL 2 times and freezes.

`Debug()` does show nothing as well. As I told seems like it froze. One core from processor loaded.

**It works Okay without goroutines. Can you help me to figure out, why it doesn't work in goroutines?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

maybe my approach is bad and you can suggest, how to fix it. In the end, file should be uploaded to S3 (for example)

Comment: Is there code after the goroutine call that keeps the program open? Do you have a `defer db.Close()` call that would interfere with the data fetching?

Comment: @Jesse sure, all exists. Code in question was edited according to your question

Comment: can you try using `sync.WaitGroup` to lock the `goroutines` before the program ends?

Comment: ... and why do you have `for {}`?

Comment: @kkesley  `for {}` keeps application working

Comment: @OlegSobchuk The `for {}` needs to be in your main function. I bet if you commented out `defer db.Close()` your issue goes away.

Comment: @Jesse `for {}` is in `main` function. If I commented out `defer db.Close()` then no changes...

Comment: @kkesley thanks `sync.WaitGroup` helped. You can add answer and I'll check it as correct. Maybe you can explain why it works with `sync.WaitGroup` and not with `loop`. Thanks

Comment: Hi @OlegSobchuk, I'm not sure what do you mean by `loop`. I can't see any loop in the main function. I've answered your question. But let me know if anything is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for all goroutines to complete before exiting the program.

```
func main() {
  ... // init DB connection etc
  wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
  defer db.Close()
  wg.Add(1) // number of goroutines
  go fetch(db, &wg)
  wg.Wait() // wait for goroutines before exiting
}

func fetch(db *gotm.DB, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
  .... // some code counts pages, creates file etc
  sqlLimit := 20000 // set limit
  for i := 0; i < pages; i++ {
    db.Table("reports_bookings"),Debug().Where(sql).Offset(i * sqlLimit).Limit(sqlLimit).Find(&myModels)
    .... // code: push it to file
    for {} // keeps open process
  }
}
```

Otherwise, your program would exit before your goroutines are finished